# Inline conversion of graphics

Tags: graphics, luatex, convert

I'm using luatatex 1.0.4 on Linux.

I read several articles about directly converting image files within the LaTeX process. But somehow I fail to use it properly for converting gif-files on the fly. I have the following folder structure:

```
+   main folder
       main.tex
|
-+ image folder
       abc.tex
       MySample.gif
```

the `abc.tex` contains simply

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./images/MySample.gif}
```

and the `main.tex` has

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.gif, .ps, .eps, .png}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{%
  convert #1 \OutputFile         
}
%\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .gif`-gif-converted-to.png}
%\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{mogrify -format png}
%\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .gif`-gif-converted-to.png}
%\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 -set filename:base "\%[basename]" "\%[filename:base]-gif-converted-to.png"}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}

\begin{document}
Include gif-Image
\input{./images/abc}
\end{document}
```

If I comment the package `arabluatex` than I cannot compile cause `Undefined control sequence. \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule`. If I leave it on the log-file says:

```
(./images/abc.tex
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <./images/MySample.gif>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2019-01-21 14:32:08
(epstopdf)                    size: 835 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <./images/MySample-gif-converted-to.png>
(epstopdf)             Command: <`convert ./images/MySample.gif `dirname ./image
s/MySample.gif`/`basename ./images/MySample.gif .gif`-gif-converted-to.png>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 3.
system(`convert ./images/MySample.gif `dirname ./images/MySample.gif`/`basename 
./images/MySample.gif .gif`-gif-converted-to.png) executed.
Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <./images/MySample-gif-converted-to.png>.


! Package luatex.def Error: File `./images/MySample-gif-converted-to.png' not f
ound.
```

From the logs I would conclude the conversion is done. I tried the different commented approaches but none of them succeeded.

Comment: Under Linux, why not install Image Magick or the fork Graphics Magick and convert all GIFs to PNGs in the command line manually? It is actually easier, except if your GIFs change a lot.

Comment: `\`convert #1 \`dirname #1\`/\`basename #1 .gif\`-gif-converted-to.png` looks wrong, the `\`` should at least be before the `.gif` or the space should be gone.

Comment: Try first without some complicated directory structure.

Comment: The reason for inlining it is that the conversion is done automatically. Therefore the command line is nice but not usable for my scenario.  Honestly I do not understand how to write it properly, e.g. `\`convert #1 \`dirname #1\`/\`basename #1.-gif-converted-to.png` does not help neither :-( I do not get any kind of converted pics neither in the folder nor in its sub.

Comment: you need to use --shell-escape which is a security risk unless you have full knowledge of all the tex code, and you convert the file every time which is slow, why not simply run convert before running tex? The eps to pdf conversion is different as it is allowed to run without --shell-escape using a restricted version of ghostscript running in safe mode

Comment: @Carlisle: I do not understand properly cuz _slow_ conversion is something I do not perceive. _Security risk_ is something I do not understand - the shell commands are under my hood and I expect that the rest of the _regular_ TeX code (and their packages) are secure. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same graphics rule you already use for `.tif`, so

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{%
  convert #1 \OutputFile         
}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}

\begin{document}
Include gif-Image
\input{./images/MySample}
\end{document}
```

works fine.
The `epstopdf` package does not rely on LuaTeX, it works with `pdfTeX` too because it is based on shell commands.
To allow TeX to execute arbitrary shell commands like `convert`, you have to compile the document with shell-escape enabled, so run

```
lualatex -shell-escape main
```

instead of

```
lualatex main
```

Comment: Thx for this hint (`shell-escape`) cause I didn't find it properly. This saved my day :-)